# How can I use MPMoviePlayerController within my application?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm having trouble implementing MPMoviePlayerController. I've downloaded and run the MoviePlayer app, and it works fine, but I'm unable to reproduce this functionality in my own app. I have added the MediaPlayer Framework and imported  to my app.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

**UITableViewController class:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section==1) {
        MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = 
(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate initAndPlayMovie:[self localMovieURL]];
    }
}
```

**MyAppDelegate:**

```
-(void)initAndPlayMovie:(NSURL *)movieURL
{
    // Initialize a movie player object with the specified URL
    MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    if (mp)
    {
        self.moviePlayer = mp;
        [mp release];       
            [self.moviePlayer play];
    }
}
```

I did some debugging in

```
- (void) moviePreloadDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
   NSLog(@"moviePreloadDidFinish");
}
```

and in

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
   NSLog(@"moviePlayBackDidFinish");
}
```

I noticed that the movie loads correctly and plays, I guess somewhere in the background, for the appropriate amount of time, but I just can't see the Movie Player. The view never changes from my TableViewController!

Any Ideas? Please help!!!

Comment: Is there sound? Have you tried -setFullScreen:animated: --> http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMoviePlayerController/setFullscreen:animated:

Comment: No there's no sound. and -setFullScreen:animated didn't work either!